# How do you pass values in a gravity forms dropdown field to a hidden field and at the same time update the value in the hidden field?

Tags: php, gravityforms

I'm trying to figure out the best approach that will allow for values within a dropdown or radio button field to be copied to a hidden field and have those values be updated within that hidden field.

See use case example below.

Dropdown has following values:

- Adoptable (when this value is selected, it will be copied to a hidden field and updated to a value of A)
- Hold (when this value is selected, it will be copied to a hidden field and updated to a value of H)
- Adopted (when this value is selected, it will be copied to a hidden field and updated to a value of X)
- Pending (when this value is selected, it will be copied to a hidden field and updated to a value of P)

I've looked at:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/allow-field-to-be-populated-dynamically/ and https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_value_parameter_name/ but with no luck.

This is for a non-profit animal rescue organization that we are doing pro-bono work for, so hiring a third party developer to troubleshoot this is not possible.

If anyone knows of a better approach and can share, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a plugin, I would suggest Gravity Perks Copy Cat by Gravity Wiz: 
https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-copy-cat/

When using the drop-down field, add the labels "Adoptable, Hold and Pending".  Make the corresponding values "A, X, and C"

Then you simply add "copy-{dropdown_field_id}-to-{hidden_field_id}" to the css field of the dropdown.

The user can select by the labels and the copy-cat feature will add the value to the hidden field.